# nearbyint cannot be found in Cygwin but works with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, mingw

I have a project needs to be compiled with Cygwin. I need to use [nearbyint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nearbyint) from math.h (or cmath). However, even though I can compile this test program with MinGW, Cygwin does not work. A workaround in Cygwin is to `#include math.h` and call without `std::` prefix. On the other hand, this approach does not work for `nearbyintl`. What is the cause of this?

Simplified example code from [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nearbyint). Compile with `-std=c++11`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfenv>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::nearbyint(2.3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::nearbyintl(2.3) << std::endl;
}
```